# How to ignore unknown enum values in xml deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I found this link
[How can I ignore unknown enum values during json deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752075/how-can-i-ignore-unknown-enum-values-during-json-deserialization)
for json deserialization.

is this same possible in xml deserialization?

how can we achieve this by using IXmlSerializable intererface

Comment: Please try `XmlIgnore` http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/XMLIgnore.aspx

Comment: I wanted to deserialize the enum values which is available in my enum list. anything which is not identified in my list, that must not be deserialized. XmlIgnore is used to ignore the property to be dederialized

Comment: Are you able to set the enum as nullable? `EnumType?`. Unknown mapping will be ignored and set to null.

Comment: enum types cannot be nullable

Comment: Only public properties in the c# classes get deserialized.  So making properties private will ignore values.

Comment: Are you using `XmlSerializer`?  If so do [XmlSerializer: How to Deserialize an enum value that no longer exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10708240), [How to ignore invalid enum values during xml deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59247332), [XmlSerializer with new enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621306) and [Skipping Invalid Values On Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28782773) answer your question?